# Removing special Character + from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please could you assist me, I'm trying to remove (Update the record)the first character in a string, in this case its a `"+"` sign

**MyTable**

```
+12334
+23343
+23443
+23432
```

**Result**

```
12334
23343
23443
23432
```

Will something like the below work?

```
update MyTable
set [F Number] = Right([F Number],LEN([F Number]) - 1)
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Hi @AjayGupta yes did try it, takes out more than I need...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tag added

Comment: Something's wrong with the db values then, because this `Select Right('+23343',LEN('+23343') - 1)` works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET [F Number] = 
CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('+', [F Number]) = 1
    THEN SUBSTRING([F Number], 2, LEN([F Number]))
    ELSE [F Number]
END
```

In this way you remove the + only if is the first char else you don't remove it

My case study:

```
CREATE TABLE #APP (name varchar(50))
insert into #app values ('+aaa'), ('aaa+aaa'), ('bbb')

select CHARINDEX('+', name), SUBSTRING(name, 2, LEN(name)), * from #app

UPDATE #app
SET name = 
CASE
   WHEN CHARINDEX('+', name) = 1
   THEN SUBSTRING(name, 2, LEN(name))
   ELSE name
END

select * from #app
```

You can see [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5618a/1/0) too

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it to INT and convert it back.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET [F Number] = CAST(CAST([F Number] AS INT) AS NVARCHAR(50))
```

If [F Number] contains non-number text, add a `WHERE` check.

```
WHERE ISNUMERIC([F Number]) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This one may help you:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyColumn = RIGHT(MyColumn, LEN(MyColumn) - 1)
```

This is working frine for me.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the `STUFF()` function, which makes this quite simple:

```
update MyTable
    set [F Number] = stuff([F Number], 1, 1, '');
```

I would be inclined to add a `where` clause, to be sure only the values you want to change are changed:

```
update MyTable
    set [F Number] = stuff([F Number], 1, 1, '')
    where [F Number] like '+%';
```